# QED Soft Theorems and Momentum Conserving $\delta$ function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, research-level, s-matrix-theory, infrared-radiation

The sub-leading soft theorem (or Low theorem) states that the radiative Feynman amplitude is associated to the non-radiative Feynman amplitude in the following way
$$\mathcal{M}_{\text{rad}}(\omega_k,\vec{k};\{p\})=\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}\frac{e_i\eta_i\epsilon_{r}^*({\vec{k}})\cdot p_i}{p_i\cdot k}+i\epsilon_{r\mu}^*({\vec{k}})k_{\nu} \sum_{i=1}^{n+m}\frac{e_i\eta_iJ_i^{\mu\nu}}{p_i\cdot k}\bigg]\mathcal{M}_0$$
where $k$ is the soft momentum of the radiated photon, $p_i$ and $e_i$ is the momentum and charge of the emitting particle (the one by which the photon is emitted), $\eta_i=\pm1$, depending on whether the emitting fermion is outgoing or incoming and $J_i$ is the fermion's total angular momentum. $\mathcal{M}_0$ is the non-radiative amplitude. $n$ and $m$ are the numbers of the incoming/outgoing fermions. The theorem holds in this form in the massless case and it can be proven diagrammatically.

Then I have the definition of the scattering matrix element (or at least its non trivial part)
$$S_{\text{rad}}(\omega_k,\vec{k};\{p\})=(2\pi)^4\delta^4(\sum_{i=1}^np_i-\sum_{i=1}^mp_i-k)\mathcal{M}_{\text{rad}}(\omega_k,\vec{k};\{p\})$$
If I want to expand $S_{\text{rad}}$ in powers of $k$, I will get subleading (i.e. $\mathcal{O}(k^0)$) contributions from the radiative Feynman amplitude evaluated in $k=0$ times the derivative  of the delta function plus subleading contributions from the radiative Feynman amplitude times the delta function evaluated at $k=0$. I see two problems with that procedure:

1. What it means to take the derivative of a delta function?
2. How can the radiative Feynman amplitude be defined at $k=0$. It is divergent.

Is the procedure of "expanding the S-matrix elements" wrong?

Any insight or reference will be helpful.

P.S. Radiative=describes the single photon radiation

Comment: For the case of soft gravitons, I have found a section in a paper talking about the delta function's derivative and that terms containing such derivatives cancel (if I understood correctly)...

The article is written by Subhroneel Chakrabarti, Sitender Pratap Kashyap, Biswajit Sahoo , Ashoke Sena and Mritunjay Verma and it's called "Testing subleading multiple soft graviton theorem for CHY prescription"

Comment: Also, I find in the paper "Classical and quantum results on logarithmic terms in the soft theorem in four dimensions" by Biswajit and Ashoke that in D<4 dimensions such terms originating from the derivative of the delta function (again, if I understand correctly) do not contribute in the scattering amplitude. Can anyone explain why??

Comment: $J_{\mu\nu} \delta^4(\cdots) = 0$.

Comment: Hi @Prahar and thank you so much for your answer. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that the additional term involving derivatives acting on the delta function, will be proportional to the total angular momentum, and hence vanish due to angular momentum conservation? Sorry if I am requesting from you to state the obvious :)